# Caching data from a DataContext

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

We're using a Linq-to-SQL DataContext in a web application that provides read-only data to the application and is never updated (have set ObjectTrackingEnabled = false to enforce this.

Since the data never changes (except for occasional config updates) it seems wasteful to be reloading it from SQL Server with a new DataContext for each web request.

We tried caching the DataContext in the Application object for all requests to use, but it was generating a lot of error and our research since shows that this was a bad idea, DataContext should be disposed of within the same unit of work, not thread safe, etc, etc.

So since the DataContext is meant to be a data access mechanism, not a data store, we need to be looking at caching the data that we get from it, not the context itself.

Would prefer to do this with the entities and collections themselves so the code can be agnostic about whether it is dealing with cached or "fresh" data.

How can this be done safely?

First, I need to make sure that the entities and collections are fully loaded before I dispose of the DataContext.  Is there a way to force a full load of everything from the database conveniently?

Second, I'm pretty sure that storing references to the entities and collections is a bad idea, because it will either

(a) cause the entities to be corrupted when the DataContext goes out of scope or

(b) prevent the DataContext from going out of scope

So should I clone the EntitySets and store them?  If so, how?  Or what's the go here?

Comment: Seems wasteful != performance bottleneck.  Where does *measuring* and *profiling* show your application to be slow?  That's where you should focus your efforts.  This is one area of software where intuition is mostly wrong.

Comment: Hi mellamokb, thanks for the comment.  It's true, we haven't attempted to measure.  But how could it not be wasteful to reload static data via a connection/SQL request/disk access for each web request when you know it will only change on a weekly basis?  Are you saying that some other caching will intrinsically happen further down the data pipeline?

Comment: No I'm saying that you shouldn't randomly add caching code when you don't know what your performance problem is.  What are you going to cache?  Every single query?  Specific tables?  There is a trade-off between caching memory and database speed, and if you use up all your memory your application will be even slower.  You can't answer all these questions by gut feel.  How do you know if a cache layer you've added has done the job?  Because certain parts of the application *feel* faster?  That's not a way to improve performance objectively.

Comment: I'm *not saying* that it's not wasteful.  I'm *not saying* you can't improve performance by doing that.  By all means if you can do something then do it!  But if you don't really know the problem you are attacking, and you don't have a number to measure how you're doing, then what is your goal and how are you going to get there?  Addressing performance by gut feel and instinct is entirely the wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, mellamokb.  I take your point, and I accept your scolding.  Still you haven't actually added anything constructive here.  For the sake of argument, let's pretend that I _do_ have a quantitative analysis method.  What's the best way to cache the data from a DataContext?  It's not a big dataset (~5MB) so the memory impact of caching will be small, especially since I will be relieving the server of repetitive DataContext lifecycles with each request.

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but I suggest avoiding caching on web site side.
I would rather focus on optimizing database queries for faster and more efficient data retrieval.

Caching will:

- not be scalable
- need extra code for synchronization, I assume your data isn't completely static in DB?
- extra code will be bug prone
- will eat up memory of your web server quickly, the next thing you might end up addressing is memory issue on your web server
- will not work very well, when you need to load-balance your web site

**[Edit]**

If I needed to cache 5MB data, I would use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) object, probably with lazy loading. I would use a set of lightweight collections, like `ReadonlyCollection<T>`, `Collectino<T>`. I would probably use `ReadonlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` also for quick searches in the memory. I would use LINQ-to-Objects to manipulate with the collections.

Comment: Hi Alex, good points, but for the time being, I really am trying to just read the entire structured dataset into memory for all threads to share.  It's not a big dataset (~5MB) so the memory impact of caching will be small, especially since I will be relieving the server of repetitive DataContext lifecycles with each request.  Really just wanting to know the best way of doing it.  I can work out the relative merits later, once I actually have the cache operating.

Comment: @Stephen - if this is just 5 MB, why do you think that data retrieval is an issue?

Comment: I've already got in trouble from mellamokb for not having any facts behind my gut feeling, don't you start! :) This is data that is repeatedly needed for every web request and almost never changes.  I'm just trying to set things up defensively where it seems obvious to me that efficiencies can be made, rather than have to deal with a manifest issue later.

Comment: @Stephen - I see what you mean. I suggest using `Cache` object then.

Answer (score 0):

You want to cache the data retrieved from the DataContext rather than the DataContext object itself.  I usually refactor out commonly-retrieved data into methods that I can implement silent caching with, something like this (may need to add thread-safe logic):

```
public class MyBusinssLayer {

    private List<MyType> _myTypeCache = null;
    public static List<MyType> GetMyTypeList() {
        if (_myTypeCache == null) {
            _myTypeCache = // data retrieved from SQL server
        }

        return _myTypeCache
    }

}
```

This is the simplest pattern that can be used and will cache for one web request.  To cache for longer periods, store the contents in a longer-term storage, such as `Application` or `Cache`.  For instance, to store in `Application` level data, use this kind of pattern.

```
public static List<MyType> GetMyTypeList() {
    if (Application["MyTypeCacheName"] = null) {
        Application["MyTypeCacheName"] = // data retrieved from SQL server
    }

    return (List<MyType>)Application["MyTypeCacheName"];
}
```

This would be for data that almost never changes, such as a static collection of status types to choose from in a `DropDownList`.  For more volitile data, you can use the `Cache` with a timeout period, which should be selected based on how often the data changes.  With the `Cache` items can be invalidated manually with code if necessary, or with a depedency checker like [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks this is good!  I'm wondering if I can use as MyType the Linq-to-SQL Entity and EntitySet objects themselves, in other words, create a complete "offline" copy of the database.  This way I still get the advantage of the associations and the code can remain ignorant of whether the DataContext is present or not.  But don't L2S entities retain some connection to their originating DataContext that will then prevent it from going out of scope?

Comment: If you load the data and call `ToList()` to make sure it is pulled from the database, then as long as you don't follow an association to retrieve data that must be lazy-loaded (i.e., not already available), that should work.  In fact, you can use the `DataLoadOptions` to specify which related associations should be retrieved at the same time, and you could literally download your entire database into an in-memory collection with a single call to the database.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but don't the entities "belong" to their DataContext somehow, even with ObjectTrackingEnabled=false?  I seem to remember having to clone entities in a previous project in order to detach them from their context and use them somewhere else.

Comment: @Stephen: It depends on how you are using them.  If you are just reading them from a collection for databinding, say to a GridView, then it doesn't matter how they were produced.  As long as it's read-only, you can freely use them however you wish.  Where it get's challenging is if you are trying to follow associations for related objects, and you haven't loaded all the necessary data.  Then it will want to try to connect to the original data source and do lazy-loading of the missing data.

Comment: And will it find the original data source?  Thoroughly timed out, but still stuck in memory because of the entity references to it?  That's the situation I'm concerned about creating.